# Creating layout of divs

Tags: css, layout, css-float

I want to create layout of divs like: [image: that] The problem is I need to create it in a row, I mean it will be posts and the last is the biggest in the center and other 4 are on the sides. I will use query, thats why I need to create in this way (I can't get 5 dives and every one with own css).

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/kys2qzne/

```
<div class="grid-all" >
    <div class="grid-item" style=" background-color: blue;"></div>
    <div class="grid-item" style=" background-color: yellow;"></div>
    <div class="grid-item height2" style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="grid-item" style=" background-color: green;"></div>
    <div class="grid-item" style=" background-color: black;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simple solution using `float` hope it helps. Thank you.

**Edited** with your last comment.
using `position property` and `nth-child` css properties.

```css
.grid-all{
  position:relative;
  width:400px;
}
.grid-item{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.height2{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:100px;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(4){
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  top:0px;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(5){
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  top:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-all" >
   <div class="grid-item" style=" background-color: blue;"></div>
    <div class="grid-item" style=" background-color: yellow;"></div>
    <div class="grid-item height2" style=""></div>
    <div class="grid-item" style=" background-color: green;"></div>
    <div class="grid-item" style=" background-color: black;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ty for answer. But is it possible to do it wthout this "main" wrappers? As I wrote, It will be a query

Comment: you mean only using your html without disturbing it?

Comment: Great! That's what I needed! TY mate.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution.

```css
.grid-all{
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-item{
  width: 100%;
  padding-top:25%;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.height2{
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
}

.grid-col {
  float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

.grid-col-big {
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-all" >
  <div class="grid-col">
    <div class="grid-item" style=" background-color: blue;"></div>
    <div class="grid-item" style=" background-color: yellow;"></div>
  </div>
<div class="grid-col-big">
  <div class="grid-item height2" style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>

<div class="grid-col">
    <div class="grid-item" style=" background-color: green;"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" style=" background-color: black;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ty for answer but not exactly. In html i Will have only main wrapper, the query and div. I can't insert/throw a column inside query